# Porting .NET app to Mac OS X

Tags: .net, macos, browser, c#-2.0, inno-setup

My software is built using .NET 2.0 runtime, webbrowser control and several other third party .net dll/components and finally encrypted using dotnetreactor (only my exe, not other .net dll/components) and built using inno setup maker. How do I port it to Mac OS X ? Is there any software available that can do it automatically? My first preference would be to use any setting in Visual Stduio IDE that can compile it in a Mac executable then use a setup maker for Mac OSX.

Update:

Seems like there is no direct way to do it.

Comment: I'm sure your preference is for a magical "make it so" button, but I don't think that is an option. @Pheonixblade9 talks about Mono and I agree. Look at Xamarin.com

Comment: For the InnoSetup part I have bad news. InnoSetup is only for Windows, so you'll need to remake this part from scratch with some Mac OS friendly installer.

Comment: I have never used Mac. Does Mono come pre-installed in Mac. If not then is there any way to download and install it (make it a part of the installation) if not detected by the installer on Mac. My inno setup maker downloads and start installer of .NET on Windows if not already present during installation of my software.

Comment: Lot of questions here. You should remove the inno-setup part from this question, as TLama says, it's a Windows only product but I can't make that an answer because it's a side question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is a popular cross-platform C# solution, though you will likely have to rewrite some stuff.

Comment: I have never used Mac. Does Mono come pre-installed in Mac. If not then is there any way to download and install it (make it a part of the installation) if not detected by the installer on Mac. My inno setup maker downloads and start installer of .NET on Windows if not already present during installation of my software.